# Reorder Array of Strings Z-A (reverse alphabetically)

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I have an array of strings which I need to order from Z-A:

```
Dim FolderFiles() As String
FolderFiles = ("ABC","ZYX","MNO","EFG")
```

I need to sort it in a way that it would appear as

```
Dim FolderFilesOrder() As String
'Sort here
FolderFilesOrdered = ("ZYX","MNO", "EFG","ABC")
```

Comparing only the first 3 letters is fine if there are restrictions.

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sort-array.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to sort the array.

```
Sub test()

Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim myArrray(3) As String

myArrray(0) = "ABC"
myArrray(1) = "ZYX"
myArrray(2) = "MNO"
myArrray(3) = "EFG"

'Sort array in descending
For i = LBound(myArrray) To UBound(myArrray)
    For j = i To UBound(myArrray)
        If UCase(myArrray(j)) > UCase(myArrray(i)) Then
            s1 = myArrray(i)
            s2 = myArrray(j)
            myArrray(i) = s2
            myArrray(j) = s1
        End If
    Next
Next

'results in ZYX, MNO, EFG, ABC

End Sub
```

Comment: Just realized this is the same method as used in the link in the comment from Ted :p

Comment: Yep thanks to the both of you. Didn't realise String compare was that simple :)